# What do the abbreviations L, NG, OT and Z on the lid of a cardboard drinking beaker mean?

Tags: abbreviations

On the plastic lid of a cardboard drinking beaker manufactured by Huhtamäki are the abbreviations L, NG, OT and Z, each with a little spherical knob next to it. What do the abbreviations mean, and what are the knobs used for?

Comment: Are you sure this should be on English.stackexchange and not Finnish.stackexchange? What country did you find this cup in?

Comment: By beaker do you mean drinking cup, like you would get at a cary-out (takeaway in BrE) restaurant? And by knobs little circles that can be pressed in? If so, I can say in general they are used to identify the drink. I do not know what those particular letters mean. In the US, we might have cola, diet cola, root beer, and lemon-lime. The first three are approximately the same color, so the server can press down the little circle if she is serving a group with a mix of sodas. Maybe in whatever country you are in, those letters stand for some common soft drinks?

Comment: Do you really need to [_axe_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture)?

Comment: Huhtamaki lids for use in English-speaking countries have a different selection of letters: [a representative image](https://www2.huhtamaki.com/web/foodservice-uk/product-catalogue/-/asset_publisher/MuvgDXnEkfXg/content/sip-lid-80mm) shows C, S and B for cream, sugar and black. Without evidence that this question is actually about English, I'm going to put it on hold. [Asking about what the knobs are for is *definitely* off-topic.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence that it's about the English language.

Answer (score 2):

The knobs are so that the servers can depress them, and keep track of what is in the cup.

For example, on the web, I can find a picture of a lid which has knobs labeled *diet, tea, cola, other*. When a server fills a cup with tea, they depress the knob labeled "tea" on the lid so as to make sure the customer gets the correct cup.

I have no idea what L, NG, OT, and Z are, though. They don't really sound like English abbreviations for various drinks.

Answer (score 0):

Huhtamäki is based in Finland.  Maybe L, NG, OT, and Z are initials in Finnish for the drinks sold there?  But in fact Huhtamäki produces drinking cups for many countries, so maybe L, NG, OT, and Z are initials in some other language.