# They won hundreds of dollars; five hundreds to be precise!

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, numbers

> [‘They won hundreds of dollars; five hundreds to be precise!’](https://books.google.es/books?id=sSGPsbUdzuMC&lpg=PA48&ots=qFZJ1J3g-z&dq=%22%E2%80%98They%20won%20hundreds%20of%20dollars%20on%20the%20quiz%20show%3B%20five%20hundreds%20to%20be%20precise!%E2%80%99%22&hl=es&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q=%22%E2%80%98They%20won%20hundreds%20of%20dollars%20on%20the%20quiz%20show;%20five%20hundreds%20to%20be%20precise!%E2%80%99%22&f=false)
>
> "The Name of the Number", by Michael A. B. Deakin , page 48.

In mathematics we talk about the place of the *units*, of the *tens*, of the *hundreds* etc. So 2.000 is *two hundred tens*, and 2.000.000 is *twenty thousand hundreds*.

---

**EDIT**

Also, what is the meaning of the second ***hundreds***, for example from the ones in the *Microsoft® Encarta®* Dictionary?

> noun (plural *hundreds*)
>
> 1. the number 100
> 2. a group of a hundred people or objects
> 3. an unspecified large number: *attended by hundreds*
> 4. the number that is three places to the left of the decimal point in an Arabic numeral
> 5. a bill worth a hundred dollars
> 6. a historical subdivision of English, Irish, and some North American counties
>
> *hundreds*, plural noun
>
> 1. the numbers 100 to 999
> 2. the years of a particular century: *the seventeen-hundreds*
> 3. numbers over 100, particularly as a range of Fahrenheit temperatures: F*or three days the temperature was in the hundreds.*
> 4. unspecified large numbers
>
> Microsoft® Encarta® 2009

Comment: Yes, "hundreds" is grammatical.  The author is trying to match the previous sentence's "hundreds," but "hundred" could have been written instead. It is just a stylistic choice.

Comment: Check in a dictionary as much as possible; your answer is here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hundred?q=hundred

Comment: @LPH the entry you pointed to has no example of a construction like "five hundred**s**"; since the book that OP is reading does quote one such example, unfortunately without attribution, it becomes an interesting question. I have never heard "Three hundreds" used by a native English speaker, although in some languages it is the rule.

Comment: @Conrado That is why I believe it shouldn't be used; most likely in a dictionary you would have "Two hundred(s)  was withdrawn from the account." but all you get is "Two hundred (pounds) was withdrawn from the account.". On top of that Google Books do not  give a single instance of that usage (see the link in my answer).

Comment: Related on ELL:[Why is there no plural s](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38635/why-is-there-no-plural-s-after-hundred-or-thousand-in-cardinal-numbers), with good answers.

Comment: @JohnB. What is the meaning of the second **hundreds** from the ones in the Microsoft® Encarta® Dictionary (see the edit I did in the OP)?

Comment: _They won hundreds of dollars — five **of them**, to be precise!​_ So if someone asked what them stood for, what would the answer be?

Comment: @johnb I think you should make your comment an answer, with more examples if possible.

Comment: @Conrado I just did.  Feel free to check it out.  Thanks!

Comment: @Conrado The most comprehensive source (if someone needs a copy of the OED, please let me know): https://www.oed.com/oed2/00109312

Comment: **(iii) Number and weight**. The numbers _dozen, score, hundred, thousand, million, billion_ are not pluralized when they are (part of) dependents or when, as heads, they are preceded by definite numerals (cardinal numbers): (1) _two hundred bikes / *two hundreds bikes_ (but _hundreds of bikes / *two hundreds of bikes_) (2) _a few thousand cars / *a few thousands cars_ (but _several thousands of cars / *four thousands of cars_) (3) _How many bikes were there? - About two hundred / *two hundreds_ (4) _Can you count to four thousand / *four thousands?_  shorturl.at/eistO

Answer (score 3):

***First, I will answer your original question.  Below the answer, you will find all of the information I have found about other usages for "hundreds" (there are probably some that I missed).***

---

> They won hundreds of dollars; five hundreds to be precise!

As the sources below state, the author—technically—should use "hundred" in this case.  However, the author used "hundreds" in the previous sentence, so they had the **stylistic choice** of whether they wanted to add the "-s."

In this case, the author was likely showing that the money was won in *discrete* units of $100.  On the other hand, the author could have simply been *matching* the "hundreds" from the clause before the semicolon; since they are in the same sentence, it would make sense to match the plurality of the same noun.  **It is simply a stylistic choice by the author.**

---

*I apologize for the long(ish) answer, but you have included (since your edit) many examples, so I will give you all of the information I have found.*

---

From *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (p. 308):

> The nouns *dozen, hundred, thousand,* and *million* have zero plurals when they are premodified by another quantitative word:
>
> > three *dozen* glasses
> >
> > two *hundred people*
>
> The plural form is normally used with all four nouns when an *of-* phrase follows, with or without a preceding indefinite quantitative word:
>
> > (many) *dozens* of glasses
> >
> > (many) *hundreds* of people
>
> But the zero form is common enough:
>
> > a few *million of* us, several *hundred/thousand of* them
>
> Note such combinations as:
>
> > *tens of thousands of* people
> >
> > *hundreds of millions of stars*

---

From *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (p. 396):

> We always read year date as hundreds:
>
> > In 1985 'nineteen eighty-five' [or] 'nineteen *hundred* and eighty five' <formal>
> >
> > In the 1600s 'sixteen *hundreds*'

---

From *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p. 351):

> i        a. *dozens of spiders*        b. *hundreds of voters*        [head noun + complement]
>
> ii        a. *a dozen spiders*        b. *three hundred voters*        [determiner + head noun]

---

From Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage* (p.322):

> After a number, the words *dozen, hundred, thousand, million, and billion* have no final *-s,* and *of* is not used.  This also happens after *several* and *a few.*
>
> Compare:
>
> > *five hundred* pounds
> >
> > *hundreds of* pounds
>
> > *several thousand* times
> >
> > It cost *thousands.*
>
> > a *few million years*
> >
> > *millions of* years

---

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hundred):

> > There were *hundreds of* people at the pool today.
> >
> > There were *a hundred* shirts waiting to be ironed.
>
> > He expects the total amount to be in the low *hundreds.*
>
> > The house was built in the *sixteen hundreds.*
>
> > Breakfast is at *seven hundred hours.*

Comment: The most comprehensive source (if someone needs a copy of the OED, please let me know): https://www.oed.com/oed2/00109312

Comment: Bravo! Thanks! No apology needed, the question needs long answers.

Comment: @Conrado Thank you!

Comment: It's not that [long](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/395385/365490) but interesting!

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Haha.  Thanks!

Comment: I think such usage is archaic. My source: The Gangs of New York.

Comment: @MaxB I disagree; this usage is not archaic at all.  Just because something is uncommon doesn't mean it is archaic.

Comment: **(iii) Number and weight**. The numbers _dozen, score, hundred, thousand, million, billion_ are not pluralized when they are (part of) dependents or when, as heads, they are preceded by definite numerals (cardinal numbers): (1) _two hundred bikes / *two hundreds bikes_ (but _hundreds of bikes / *two hundreds of bikes_) (2) _a few thousand cars / *a few thousands cars_ (but _several thousands of cars / *four thousands of cars_) (3) _How many bikes were there? - About two hundred / *two hundreds_ (4) _Can you count to four thousand / *four thousands?_  shorturl.at/eistO

Answer (score 2):

While it may be O.K., "five hundreds" is not usual.

The *place* of a digit in the number is called "units", "tens", "hundreds", and so on; but when talking about *quantities*, the only one to become plural is the unit: 1 **unit**, two or more **units**.
The author you quote mentions "grammar books" recommending not to use the S, like this one at [Woodwardenglish](https://www.woodwardenglish.com/million-or-millions/):

> When we have large numbers or a specific number, we do NOT put an S at the end of hundred, thousand, and million.

For example, in this report at [unesdoc.unesco.org](https://unesdoc.unesco.org/ark:/48223/pf0000131164), the number is written without the S at the end of "thousand" and "hundred", just like the one "million", although they are plural (Deakin mentions this custom rather briefly in the paragraph that you quoted):

> [...] before the end of
> 2003, the sum of one million, two hundred and eighty-two thousand, five hundred and fifty-five United States dollars (US $1,282,555) corresponding to the
> [...]

Constructions like "two hundred tens", while mathematically decipherable, are definitely uncomfortable, to say the least, and smack of gratuitous polynomial expansion.

Comment: I would expect *five hundreds* to mean 5 $100 bills, which is something a cashier might be asked for when cash is withdrawn from a bank: *Give me five hundreds and ten twenties.*

Comment: You may wish to remove this reference: *The three hundreds of Aylesbury: Introduction is the name of a chapter in A History of the County of Buckingham: Volume 2.* Unfortunately, this "hundreds" is either not related to the number at all. or only very indirectly. A hundred, in this sense is equivalent to a wapentake or a ward. It was a division of a county that had its own court.

Comment: @Greyb you're right- thank you! I will edit; I saw that it was a district after I had posted. If I cannot find the etymology of that kind of hundred I will make it a question soon.

Comment: @Greybeard Etymonline says that _hundred_ "Meaning "division of a county or shire with its own court" (still in some British place names and U.S. state of Delaware) was in Old English and probably represents 100 hides of land...

Comment: @Conrado. The important word is "probably". The OED also says "hundred" was an area that provided 100 soldiers. The derivation is uncertain. When last used (1960s?), it referred to the area of jurisdiction of a single court in a district of any size. But in legal terms in the 18th century, we have: "1765   W. Blackstone Comm. Laws Eng. I. Introd. iv. 115   *As ten families of freeholders made up a town or tithing, so ten tithings composed a superior division, called a hundred, as consisting of ten times ten families.*" The point is that it isn't a number.

Comment: @JasonBassford What is the meaning of the second **hundreds** from the ones in the Microsoft® Encarta® Dictionary (see the edit I did in the OP)?

Comment: @GJC - there are two "second" entries - which do you mean?

Comment: It's a single entry for **"hundred"**; compare the Collins entry : https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hundred

Comment: @Conrado _They won hundreds of dollars — five **of them**, to be precise!​_ So if someone asked what them stood for, what would the answer be?

Comment: @gjc Five **hundred**. Or Five **groups of a hundred**. The *first* second definition from Encarta is not (commonly, at least) used in the plural with _s_. Anyway, you erased the original question, now my answer doesn't fit!

Comment: @GJC I have added back the text from the original question that you had removed. Please do not edit a question so as to invalidate existing answers that were based on it.

Comment: **(iii) Number and weight**. The numbers _dozen, score, hundred, thousand, million, billion_ are not pluralized when they are (part of) dependents or when, as heads, they are preceded by definite numerals (cardinal numbers): (1) _two hundred bikes / *two hundreds bikes_ (but _hundreds of bikes / *two hundreds of bikes_) (2) _a few thousand cars / *a few thousands cars_ (but _several thousands of cars / *four thousands of cars_) (3) _How many bikes were there? - About two hundred / *two hundreds_ (4) _Can you count to four thousand / *four thousands?_  shorturl.at/eistO

Answer (score -3):

From the use in one of the examples at the entry for "[hundred](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hundred?q=hundred)" (OALD) you can see that an s is probably not used. From this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=15&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&content=%2A+hundred+to%2C%2A+hundreds+to&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bone%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfive%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btwo%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthree%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfour%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Beight%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsix%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfifteen%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfew%20hundred%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bby%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfrom%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfew%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsome%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmany%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bseveral%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btheir%20hundreds%20to%3B%2Cc0) and [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A+hundreds&year_start=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3&year_end=2008&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmany%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bby%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsome%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bare%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bseveral%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0) you have the confirmation that an s is never found after a number; it must be exceptional to find one.

Comment: Never? Oh, never _in that very particular context_

Comment: What is the meaning of the second **hundreds** from the ones in the Microsoft® Encarta® Dictionary (see the edit I did in the OP)?

Comment: @GJC I can't make out for sure what you are asking; please, try to be specific.